# Null ref when trying to find DrawerLayout view by id

Tags: java, android, sdk

I have created a new Android Studio project using Blank Activity as my template. I'm trying to make the Floating Application Button open a Navigation Drawer Activity.

My Blank Activity:

```
public class RandomizerActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    private NavigationActivity m_Navigation;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_randomizer);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        m_Navigation = new NavigationActivity();

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
                m_Navigation.openDrawer();
            }
        });
    }

    ...
}
```

My NavigationActivity:

```
public class NavigationActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener
{
    public void openDrawer()
    {
        DrawerLayout layout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        layout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    }

    ...

}
```

And the activity_navigation.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    ...

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

When I press the FAB the application crashes with a null ref error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.Window.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
```

I'm completely new to android development, so I presume I have a fundamental misunderstanding of Activity instantiation. Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong and what the correct approach is?

Comment: You're spot-on with your assessment. You can't instantiate an Activity with `new` and have it work correctly. Also, you shouldn't be trying to directly access members of one Activity from another. Normally, there is only one Activity on-screen at a time, so I'm not sure what your attempting here.

Comment: Thank you, "Normally, there is only one Activity on-screen at a time" really clarifies things for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would probably make RandomizerActivity implement the navigation drawer, which would allow you to open it from the FAB's onClick as you wish to do now.